# What is the trick to changing currency of CurrencyTextBox

Tags: dojo

I have a CurrencyTextBox where I set the currency to a default currency. The user can change it by making a selection in a currency drop down on same form. I thought I could just change the currency attribute on the textbox dynamically but nothing happens. The symbol will not change. Is there some trick to make this work? I've seen related posts that had to destroy and recreate the widget. Seems like there might be a better way?

I'd like to set the currency of unitCostId widget to the user's selected currency on the fly. The result would be that the currency symbol would change to match the newly selected currency.

```
  new CurrencyTextBox ({
        id: "unitCostId",
        name: "price",  
        currency: "USD",
        required: true,
        value: "",
        placeHolder: "Enter Price"
    }, "unitCostNode");
----------------------------------------------------
  new Select({
        id: "currencyOptionsId",
        name: "currency_code",
        value: "USD",
        options: currencyOptions,
        required: true,
        onChange: function(val) {
           var currency_id = this.get("value");
           registry.byId("unitCostId").set("currency",this.get("value");
        // registry.byId("unitCostId").reset();
         }
        }, "currencyNode");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `currency` property has no setter logic, and is documented as constant.  However, due to how the underlying code works, you can still manage to change it by setting it via `constraints` instead:

```
registry.byId("unitCostId").set("constraints", { currency: this.get("value") });
```

Comment: It worked - Thank you! Hope your solution helps someone else.